# Force SAS to continuously print results

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

Suppose I have 3 proc tabulates in SAS. SAS will only display the results when all 3 finish. Is it possible to force SAS to display each table as soon as they are completed?

Comment: Where do you want them displayed? Interactive SAS or to create output files with each having a proc tabulate result?

Comment: We use SAS enterprise guide and I would like to output the results. Enterprise Guide hides some of the work from me, but I believe they go to the "listing".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always risky to say "SAS can't do that," but I'm going to go out on a limb and say "EG can't do that."  While EG looks similar to old-fashioned Display Manager SAS, it's not really an Interactive SAS session.  It's more like doing a series of batch submits connected to the same session.  So when you submit code, it sends the code to the server, submits it, gets the results, and returns the results to EG.  It waits for all the code to finish executing before it returns the results.  I don't think this can be changed.

Comment: You could always try posting in the EG forum over at communities.sas.com. EG developers often respond over there (notably Chris Hemedinger).